# .Net core : Get header origin dynamically

Tags: asp.net-core, angular7

I'm using Angular7/.Net core web API and i need to retrieve dynamically the origin url value of the frontend through .net core API as  http://localhost:4200 or http://domainName.com.
I have used the code below but it did not match with .net core

model.origin = Request.Headers.GetValues("Origin");

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're doing cross origin request than you should indeed get the Origin header from the request. 
However not exactly as you suggest in your post.
Try:

```cs
var hasOrigin = this.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Origin",  out var origin);
```

Also if you're running behind a proxy, you will need to setup host header forwarding.
On nginx for example, you would do that like this: `proxy_set_header Host  $host;`

Comment: Request.Host returns the address of the backend url(.net core), however i need to retreive the front-end url (angular).

Comment: I'm assuming you're doing cross origin request. I updated the answer. This works when i try it on my machine. However don't forget to forward headers if there's any proxies in front of the asp.net core api.

Comment: hasOrigin is a boolean value and not the origin value ?

Comment: Yes, check the out `origin` parameter. That's how that API works.